# Authorize.net transactions are failing with several console errors regarding Access-Control-Allow-Headers. Is there a setting that's been missed?

Tags: authorize.net

We have a working dev version of this server and the Apache settings are identical (except for paths of course). However, now whenever we attempt a purchase through Authorize.net direct post, we get a series of console errors all relating to "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".  This is a CE installation and is live.

Authnet Payment Settings:
Debug On
Test Mode Off
Hash is set and confirmed.

The transactions are all successful and showing up in Authorize.net.  However, the user gets and error saying:

"Attention: Something went wrong. Please contact the seller."

The orders ARE appearing in the orders listing within Magento.

Here are the series of errors in the console:

```
GET https://URL/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/Magefan_Blog/css/blog-m.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED
transact.dll:24 GET https://URL/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/Magefan_Blog/css/blog-custom.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED
transact.dll:1 Access to Font at 'https://URL/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/fonts/opensans/bold/opensans-700.woff2' from origin 'https://secure.authorize.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://secure.authorize.net' is therefore not allowed access.
transact.dll:1 Access to Font at 'https://URL/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/fonts/opensans/bold/opensans-700.woff' from origin 'https://secure.authorize.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://secure.authorize.net' is therefore not allowed access.
transact.dll:1 Access to Font at 'https://URL/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/fonts/opensans/bold/opensans-700.ttf' from origin 'https://secure.authorize.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://secure.authorize.net' is therefore not allowed access.
jquery-migrate.min.js:6 JQMIGRATE: Logging is active
transact.dll:1 Failed to load https://URL/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/Magento_Ui/templates/modal/modal-popup.html: Request header field x-requested-with is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
transact.dll:1 Failed to load https://URL/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/Magento_Ui/templates/modal/modal-slide.html: Request header field x-requested-with is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
transact.dll:1 Failed to load https://URL/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/js-translation.json: Request header field x-requested-with is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
VM23747:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at callback (transact.dll:223)
    at Object.execCb (require.min.js:112)
    at Module.check (require.min.js:56)
    at Module.<anonymous> (require.min.js:72)
    at require.min.js:11
    at require.min.js:74
    at each (require.min.js:3)
    at Module.emit (require.min.js:74)
    at Module.check (require.min.js:61)
callback @ transact.dll:223
execCb @ require.min.js:112
check @ require.min.js:56
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:72
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:11
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:74
each @ require.min.js:3
emit @ require.min.js:74
check @ require.min.js:61
enable @ require.min.js:73
init @ require.min.js:54
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:66
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:11
(anonymous) @ text.min.js:10
xhr.onreadystatechange @ text.min.js:8
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
getContent @ text.min.js:9
loadContent @ text.min.js:10
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:71
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:11
on @ require.min.js:40
callPlugin @ require.min.js:61
fetch @ require.min.js:55
check @ require.min.js:56
enable @ require.min.js:73
enable @ require.min.js:101
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:73
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:11
each @ require.min.js:3
enable @ require.min.js:71
init @ require.min.js:54
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:97
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.min.js:117
localRequire @ require.min.js:97
configure @ require.min.js:86
requirejs @ require.min.js:116
req.config @ require.min.js:117
callback @ transact.dll:219
execCb @ require.min.js:112
check @ require.min.js:56
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:72
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:11
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:74
each @ require.min.js:3
emit @ require.min.js:74
check @ require.min.js:61
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:72
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:11
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:74
each @ require.min.js:3
emit @ require.min.js:74
check @ require.min.js:61
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:72
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:11
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:74
each @ require.min.js:3
emit @ require.min.js:74
check @ require.min.js:61
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:72
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:11
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:74
each @ require.min.js:3
emit @ require.min.js:74
check @ require.min.js:61
enable @ require.min.js:73
init @ require.min.js:54
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:66
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:11
(anonymous) @ mixins.min.js:8
execCb @ require.min.js:112
check @ require.min.js:56
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:72
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:11
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:74
each @ require.min.js:3
emit @ require.min.js:74
check @ require.min.js:61
enable @ require.min.js:73
init @ require.min.js:54
callGetModule @ require.min.js:74
completeLoad @ require.min.js:103
onScriptLoad @ require.min.js:112
transact.dll:1 Failed to load https://URL/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/Magento_Ui/templates/modal/modal-custom.html: Request header field x-requested-with is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
transact.dll:1 Failed to load https://URL/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/Magento_Ui/templates/tooltip/tooltip.html: Request header field x-requested-with is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
transact.dll:1 Failed to load https://URL/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/Magento_Ui/templates/block-loader.html: Request header field x-requested-with is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
transact.dll:1 Failed to load https://URL/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/Magento_Customer/template/authentication-popup.html: Request header field x-requested-with is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.  We use a plugin to force login to the store before any pages can be viewed.  This plugin was blocking the return of Authorize.net to the store to notify it of a successful charge.

Adding "/authorizenet" as a rule to the whitelist was the cure.

Hope this helps others.